# Update a cell every day at a specific time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

To be frank I'm a complete newb at scripting and I have went as far as submitting a request to Googles support and was directed here.

What I'm needing is to be able to update a cell in a spreadsheet every day at a certain time, also I need to be able to do this multiple times daily.

Basically what I need is for is at 8:00 PM I need the values from B4 down to be copied into D4 down. When tried using the basic functions in Google the most that can be obtained is for the minute of 8:00 PM it will update then at 8:00 1 it goes back to 0. 
If I hadn't looked for days I wouldn't be asking for help. I apologize for my newbness.

A screenshot of the sheet I'm working with can be found via my Google Drive below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2GuBHPLz-Z_TWw2ZmtxNWJ0bkU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Have a look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Comment: Thanks for what would normally be a helpful nudge but at this point in time I don't have the knowledge required to be able to put what it seems like I'm needing together. My skills are the equivalent of being an advanced Excel user.
I do appreciate the teach a man to fish mentality though @tiGer

Comment: Cron is not relevant here at all. However your question is not for so. Because its a spec looking for a coder. Here you need code and a specific problem within it. Many other sites do let you hire a coder.

Answer (score 3):

You need to set up a time-based trigger that runs around 8 PM everyday and it should call the method that will update the cell.

```
function addTrigger() {
 ScriptApp.newTrigger("updateCell").timeBased().atHour(20).everyDays(1).create();
}

function updateCell() {
  var url = "<SPREADSHEET URL HERE>";
  var cell = "<CELL in A1 Notation>";
  SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url).getRange(cell).setValue(new Date());
}
```

You'll have to run the addTrigger method once for setting this up.

Comment: Thanks, this was a great push in the right direction.